# How to refresh a layer using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

In GeoServer I configured a layer containing positions that change in time (they are smart phone positions indeed). I'am able to insert fresh position in GeoServer datastore (a PostGIS database), but I'm not able to automatically reload the layer in client side using OpenLayers.

In addition I wish to load from the layer only the information contained in the visualized BBOX (i.e. what the user will see on its screen).

Could anyone provide me a suggestion?

Comment: You should provide more info: what kind of layer (vector or bitmap)? do you insert the position from a web app embedding an OpenLayers map or via another tool (QGIS,...)? do you need all pages in the world using the layer to be updated on layer changes?

Comment: The layer is a vector one. I insert/update the position directly on postGIS DB (ie into the table I configured for layer). The refresh shall be done in all pages loaded from my web application embedding the openLayers lib.

Comment: In this case you could: 1) follow @drunkenwagoner suggestion using a timeout but, depending on the number of features, it could be appropriate to find a way to check the layer modification date so to avoid loading the layer unaltered; 2) you could implement something using websockets, that would enable you to notify the client side of changes anytime you want but would probably require more work to be accomplished

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the OpenLayers Refresh strategy?

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Refresh-js.html

It makes the layer refresh automatically after N milliseconds, and should be compatible with a bounding box (in fact you need to add a bounding box strategy as well).

```
var refresh = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({interval: 1000});

strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BoundingBox(), refresh]
```